# Spring Roo css customization

Tags: java, css, spring-roo

I'm a newbie in Java and Spring, but Spring Roo seemed to me pretty intuitive, except for the css `background:url ()` property.
That's why I'm here today, to ask if anyone knows a way of including images' url in css file (If Spring Roo permit it)?

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah this will work. In the end every homepage you see in the browser is just HTML, Javascript and CSS.
Just the way it is generated differ may differ wildly.

Try it yourself by adding the following line in the body-tag to `standard.css` which you find in the folder `resources/styles/`

```
background:url(http://www.google.de/images/srpr/logo3w.png) top left;
```